# gradle: share a zip between war projects

Tags: zip, gradle, war

I'm trying to build a kind of **template build script** for my java web projects.
This template is stored in my apache web server.
To use it in a project, I use `apply from 'http://myserver/templateWarScript.gradle'`.
The configuration for the final war is done in this template.

**For all of my java web projects, I need to put the content of a zip file (containing JavaScript files, images, etc) into the final war file.
To share this zip file, I put it in my local repository.**

Now, I'm trying to find a way to include its content in my final war. But I can't found a way to do it.
I'm trying to put the following line in my template script:

```
  configurations {
        zipWebResource
  }

   dependencies {
        zipWebResource group: 'utilities.template', name: 'webResource', version: '1.0', ext: 'zip'
   }

  //test task 
  task testZipPath << {
        println "zip path:" + configurations.zipWebResource.asPath
   }
   //

   //my war configuration
   war {
        println "zip path:" + configurations.zipWebResource.asPath
    }
```

If I put the 'configurations.zipWebResource.asPath' in the war configuration, I've got an error which shows that gradle can't find the zip dependency.
But, if I remove it from the war configuration, I can read it by my test task.

I've also try to read it in a method or directly in the gradle script, but I've got the same error. After reading the gradle user guide, I think that my problem is linked with the configuration or/and the execution phase.

**I would like to understand why I can read the *configurations.zipWebResource.asPath* in a task but not in a configuration. My goal is to use the zip like a dependency and put it's content in the root of the generated war**

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no semantic difference between including this snippet with `apply from:`, and pasting it straight into the build script (replacing the `apply from:`). Maybe you changed the order of declarations, or didn't have the zip in your local repository in one of the cases.

EDIT to reflect your new question:
In general, configurations shouldn't be resolved at configuration time, but only at execution time. In your case, `asPath` will trigger the resolution. For an external dependency, it should work though (but is not advisable because it may slow down your build). Chances are that the problem is somewhere else (e.g. wrong order of declarations).

PS: Stack Overflow isn't a good format for this kind of support without a clear-cut question. The best place to get Gradle support is: http://forums.gradle.org

Comment: The zip is already in my gradle cache. My problem is half solved. I added another **repositories closure** in the template (for the zip dependency). But now, I can't understand why 'configurations.zipWebResource.asPath' isn't accessible in my war task configuration. For instance, I can't do `war { println configurations.zipWebResource.asPath}`. 
 To access it, I must use a personal task (like the previous __testZipPath__ task). Isn't possible to access to the zipWebResource.asPath in the war configuration?

Comment: Please edit your question. Otherwise it's very difficult to follow what you are doing/asking.

Comment: A configuration *should* not be resolved in the configuration phase (because it means it will be resolved for *every* invocation of Gradle), but it *can* be resolved in the configuration phase. If it doesn't work for you, there's likely another problem with your build script. To add the contents of a zip to a war, you can do something like `war.from { zipTree(zipWebResource.singleFile) }`. The `{}` defers resolving the configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I think I'm going to keep an intermediate task to unzip the archive (the zipWebResource configuration is accessible in execution phase) and use it as a dependency task for the war. I've already tested it. 
(__From another linked build script, inside methods, I can access dependencies define in a configuration for my custom ant task__)